# bash execute on current time between two times

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a `bash` file that gets the current time, and executes `code` if the statement is true. However, `code` "never" executes. Not sure why?

```
currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
if [[ "$currenttime" > "8:29" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" < "18:30" ]]; then
   code
fi
```

Comment: please update the question with sample values of `currenttime` when the script does and does not execute `code`

Comment: one big issue is gonig to be that  you're comparing strings; consider this: `[[ "12:00" > "8:19" ]]` is going to return false because `1` is not greater than `8`; one idea would be to make sure all times are in 24-hr format (including leading zeros), eg, `[[ "12:00" > "08:19" ]]`; another option would be to convert everything to seconds (since epoch) (eg, current time= `date '+%s'`); a web search on `bash compare times` brings up quite a few hits on the topic

Comment: Yes, all true. I just found the problem. "8:29" is not the same as "08:29"

Comment: Right. `>` is a string operator, and it uses lexicographical comparision, i.e. dictionary order. Looking at "08:30" and "8:29", the "0" is less than "8", therefore `[[ $time > "8:29" ]]` fails. In fact, no hour given by `%H` is `>` "8"

Comment: You could do `currenttime=$(date '+%-H%M')` then the time "08:30" is reported as "830", and you can use an arithmetic comparision: `if (( currenttime > 830 && currenttime < 1830 ))`

Comment: Also, bash's `printf` command can do strftime with it's `%(time-format)T` format directive: `printf -v currenttime '%(%-H%M)T' -1` where "-1" is a magic value that means "now".

Comment: use millis instead string date format